# How to change font size of address bar in Chrome programmatically

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to change the font size of the address bar in Chrome programmatically since it's too big for me.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid all we can do for now is **star** [this](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=276946) issue. This way it should get more attention of the developers. But I am skeptical about it. They're seems to be deaf and now also blind.

Comment: Three years on, and in version 53 it's become smaller...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, the font size of the address bar is determined by your OS's default font size. Read comments here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=46472. So if you want to adjust it, change your OS default.

If you build your own version of Chrome, you can change the look and feel of the browser, but you'll have to write different code for each platform you want to support.

If you don't want to build your own version of Chrome, then on Windows, you can inject yourself into the Chrome process with SetWindowsHook or SetWindowsHookEx, find the window handle corresponding to the address bar, and then do anything you want to it. [Similar idea](https://github.com/rentzsch/mach_star) on OSX. Not sure about Linux. This isn't a recommended approach; it's invasive and subject to breakage.

As far as a Chrome API for an extension or app to change the address bar size, nope, can't do that.

Comment: Good Answer; it is surprising to me we cannot increase the font size of the chrome address bar. when searching for extensions there are none. Firefox has some.

Answer (score -1):

Please check https://superuser.com/questions/461982/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows-8. In my case HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics key was missed.

Comment: Windows only answer is not what was asked