# Programmatically change font type for title and address bar in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, webkit

How to programmatically change the font type for title and address bar in Chrome?

For example, Amazon uses different font type for title on specific pages:

[image: amazon css for address bar and title]

As per [How to change font size of address bar in Chrome programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343740/how-to-change-font-size-of-address-bar-in-chrome-programmatically) getting Windows handle by injecting into Chrome process seems to be the only way.

Are there any alternate ways to achieve this? Like CSS?

Comment: You cannot modify the fonts of the tabs or address bar.

Comment: You cant do this via CSS. That an OS thing.

Answer (score 0):

The think that causes this is the ™ character in the `<title>`. This is a bug in Chrome that causes the font to switch if certain characters are present.

You can thus replicate this by simply including this character at the end of every single `<title>` you generate. I would definitely advise against it, because relying on bugs is an incredibly bad idea, but none the less it *is* possible at least for now.